# FS on NFS share responding slow

Tags: linux, files, nfs

We have two server ex name app1 and app2.Both server have a nfs mount from same server as below:-

```
nfsserver:/prlocal  249G  190G   46G  81% /prlocal
```

Now the problem is when we try to access the FS via app1 , it is slower than compare to app2.

Like

on app1

```
[root@app1:/prlocal]#time ls -l

real    0m0.331s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.030s
```

on app2

```
[root@app2:/prlocal]#time ls -l
real    0m0.034s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.009s
```

What is wrong with app1?

Comment: Next time use more shift, it is important.

Comment: can you add more details ? number of CPU, memory, CPU usage, network. if you run multiple time `time ls -l` , are result faster second time ?

Comment: @peterh what do you mean by more shift , i didn't get it.

Comment: @Archemar By running time ls -l results are not faster.though they are fluctuating but for app1 its always remains high. And I want to add one more important thing tha Memory of app1 is less than app2.

Comment: @abhimanyusingh Do you see my fixes to your question? This is the required style here.

Comment: @peterh Got it.